# At what point in my scripts should I include/require PHP files (i.e. including a class)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been teaching myself OOP PHP over the last few months while developing a Wordpress plugin and one of the things I have struggled to find a clear answer on is if I need a class/method within some code, at what point should I include the other script.

**Example**

For example, imagine I need to access this method:

```
// File name = usefulfunctions.php

class usefulFunctions {

    public static function multiply ($input, $multiplier) {

        return $input * $multiplier;

    }

}
// Initiate Static Class
new usefulFunctions();
```

In for the following file to work:

```
// Option 1: require it at the top of the file
require_once('usefulfunctions.php');

class multiplier {

    public function __construct($input){
        // Option 2: require it when the class is initiated
        require_once('usefulfunctions.php');
        $this->input = $input;
    }

    public function multiply_by_five ($input) {

        // Option 3: require it in the function itself
        require_once('usefulfunctions.php');

        $output = usefulFunctions::multiply($input, 5);
        return $output;

    }

}

$my_multiplier = new multiplier(42);
$my_multiplier->multiply_by_five();
```

**What I am stuck on**

I don't know which of the three options I suggested above is the best.

1) Include at the top of the file
2) Include in the __construction function
3) Include within the function that the method is required

Currently I just 'require_once' everything in the main plugin file which I am sure is very inefficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe ask this in the codereview website?

Comment: Look into autoloading classes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Thanks @naththedeveloper.

Comment: @Akintunde I don't think this query is suitable for that website as I am asking about a coding principle, not to review actual code. The code above is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to include it at the top of your file, because you might need it in several functions, and because if there is a problem with the required file, your process will be stopped before it goes any further.